# Make raster images "unselectable" like vector images

Tags: graphics

In Adobe, clicking a raster image (jpg, png...) selects it, i.e. creates a blue box around it and brings up an action menu. In Sumatra PDF, right-clicking a raster image lets you "copy image". In both programs, vector images (e.g. eps) cannot be interacted with in any such way.

Is there a way to include a raster image but make it so you can't interact with it in this way?

Comment: This is a feature of your PDF reader, and nothing that LaTeX has control over. You might be able to set a security flag with Adobe Acrobat or some other external PDF software to disallow copying , that in turn might be respected by some PDF readers, but really – why bother? If somebody can open your PDF they can copy its contents, one way or another.

Comment: On the plus side, raster images are usually copied at 72 dpi and look awful.